# How to upgrade yolk to yolk3k in a virtual env?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, yolk

I have just started using `virtualenv` from this [tutorial](http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/), where it uses `yolk` to list the packages installed in the `virtualenv`, but `yolk` by default is for *Python 2*, so I decided to upgrade with an extension for *Python 3*, my current version, with the following command:

`pip3 install --upgrade yolk3k`

It works when I am not in the *virtualenv* that I called `virt0`, but if I am on it, it gives me the error it was giving me before upgrading it to the *Python 3* version.

```
    print " %s %s (%s)" % (project_name, dist.version,
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I tried to install `yolk` in the `virt0`, the output was the following:

```
Searching for yolk
Best match: yolk 0.4.3
Processing yolk-0.4.3-py3.4.egg
yolk 0.4.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing yolk script to /Users/user/Desktop/virt_env/virt0/bin

Using /Users/user/Desktop/virt_env/virt0/lib/python3.4/site-packages/yolk-0.4.3-py3.4.egg
Processing dependencies for yolk
Finished processing dependencies for yolk
```

In `/Users/user/Desktop/virt_env/virt0/bin`, I have this:

```
activate            pip3
activate.csh        pip3.4
activate.fish       python
activate_this.py    python3
easy_install        python3.4
easy_install-3.4    yolk
pip
```

which confirms that `yolk` was installed, but how can I update it also to `yolk3k` in `virt0`?

If I try to install `yolk3k` with the following command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade yolk3k
```

inside `/Users/user/Desktop/virt_env/virt0/bin`, it outputs:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: yolk3k in /Users/user/Desktop/virt_env/virt0/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

but it still gives me the error I cited above.

Comment: Has the virtual environment been activated?

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes, I have activated... and actually that is the actual problem, where I am on the vitualenv `virt0` :D

Comment: Can you please show the actual list of commands you executed and their outputs?

Comment: Please include all these information in the question itself.

Comment: @thefourtheye Fortunately, apparently, I can list the installed packages in the _virtualenv_ `virt0` using the normal _pip3_ with the following command: `pip3 list`, if you someone could help me also with `yolk`, it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the virtualenv, recreate it with Python 3 as the interpreter and install all dependencies for Python 3 (such as `yolk3k`). The problem seems to come from the fact that you're going from a 2.x to a 3.x environment even though the virtualenv originally wasn't.

That's not the intended way of using a virtualenv - a virtualenv should be tied to one particular Python version (e.g., 2.7 or 3.4) with all dependencies installed for that version. So you should throw away the virtualenv and rebuild it entirely using 3.x dependencies. That should resolve any conflicting language issues.